# HDFS I/O statistics in command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs, monitoring

Is there any way to get the I/O stat(i.e total read i/o, write i/o) for hadoop/hdfs cluster? May be something like `iostat`in Linux? I know there is a way to see the stat in webUI.

> http://<namenode_host>:50070/jmx

But I need to access the stat in command line. Is there any way to get the webUI content in the commandline? or maybe some other tool? I am using Amazon EMR for Hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and query using jmxterm.

https://docs.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm

Please not that this requires having jmx enabled in your nodes. Additionally, for some Hadoop distros (Not sure about Amazon EMR) There are requirements for the connections to not use authentication.

The other thing that you could do is poll the URLs with curl, and parse the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am doing the second one. But it returns a very long json object. Do you know which metrics can indicate the total read, write i/O size, or rate?

Comment: If you are doing the second option, i would look at the webui, and identify the values that are of interest to you. Then i would identify any headrs/titles that make them recognizable on the web ui, and i would parse for those on the json.